# Cambié el icono de un JFrame, lo volvi a dejar como estaba, ahora me da error al compilar

Tags: java, java-swing

Mi proyecto estaba funcionando, al cambiar el icono del JFrame, ya me aparece error al compilar.

```
package pruebaint;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class ventana extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{

/**
 * Creates new form ventana
 */
public ventana() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    lblMenu = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    btnInd = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnCal = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnAcc = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnSalir = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("PRENDAS");

    lblMenu.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 48)); // NOI18N
    lblMenu.setText("MENÚ");

    btnInd.setText("INDUMENTARIAS");
    btnInd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnIndActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnCal.setText("CALZADOS");

    btnAcc.setText("ACCESORIOS");

    btnSalir.setText("Salir");
    btnSalir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnSalirActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/juan_opt (80x80).png"))); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
            .addComponent(lblMenu)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(61, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(btnAcc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 268, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnCal, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 268, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnInd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 268, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(45, 45, 45)))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(btnSalir, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(140, 140, 140))))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(lblMenu)
                    .addGap(68, 68, 68))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 20, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addComponent(btnInd, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addComponent(btnCal, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(btnAcc, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addComponent(btnSalir, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnIndActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    opcionesIndumentaria obj = new opcionesIndumentaria();
    obj.setVisible(true);
    dispose();

}                                      

private void btnSalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Icon icono = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/juan_opt.png"));
    Icon icono2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(""));

   int op = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Está seguro que desea salir?", "Confirmar salida", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, icono);
   if(op==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
   {
       System.exit(0);
   }

}                                        

public static void main(String args[]) 
{

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ventana().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnAcc;
private javax.swing.JButton btnCal;
private javax.swing.JButton btnInd;
private javax.swing.JButton btnSalir;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblMenu;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

El error que aparece es este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El fallo lo tienes en esta línea.. `jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/juan_opt (80x80).png"))); // NOI18N`. Tendrás que quitar barra inclinada del principio, y mirar si el nombre de la imagen es correcto como lo tienes. Se supone que apuntas a la carpeta de recursos, y dentro tienes que tener otra carpeta con el nombre imagenes y dentro la imagen `getResource("imagenes/juan-opt.png")`

Answer (score 1):

> Cambié el icono de un JFrame, lo volví a dejar como estaba, ahora me da **error** al compilar

El error se encuentra en esta línea de tu código..

```
jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/juan_opt (80x80).png"))); // NOI18N
```

Tendrás que quitar *barra inclinada del **principio***, y mirar si el nombre de la imagen es correcto como lo tienes.

Se supone que apuntas a la carpeta de recursos con `getClass().getResource()`, el cual nos devuelve una **URL** 'Encuentra un recurso con un nombre dado.' , y dentro tienes que tener otra carpeta con el nombre imagenes y dentro la imagen `getResource("imagenes/juan-opt.png");`

Answer (score 0):

Puede que hayas borrado el/los archivos de Icon y cuando haces el new en el metodo btnSalirActionPerformed tire NullException.